# Displacement through Geometry Nodes and vertex paint as masking

Tags: geometry-nodes, displacement

I'm new to geometry nodes.

Trying to set position with attribute color data as a mask (mask is the same on the other side), but there's an offset in the mesh, I need it to be symmetrical. Hoping to make the set position work along normals, could anyone help me fix this?

[Example File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qAppUxrl3aJg4xKaNZyCcPk2ivDuPrvo/view?usp=share_link)

[image: Vertex paint as Mask]

[image: Displacement working]

[image: Offset in mesh]

[image: GeoNode Setup]

Comment: if you provide a blend file...i will try

Comment: Thank you so much , this is just the beginning of a more complex setup. Hope this is enough to understand. PLEASE SEE ORIGINAL POST [ added a drive link ]

Comment: ok, problem 1 is that your model isn't perfectly in the middle...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with this node tree:

[image]

i simplified it a bit, but i hope you understand the principle.

you get this:

[image]

The trick is:

you have to give the voronoi the same positions to both x-sides.

By this you will get the same pattern.

Unfortunately you didn't tell me that the midpoint wasn't 0 but -1. So i needed some more time to figure that out.

further explanation: The voronoi texture use the position input to generate a random value. This value is always the same for the same input values. If you plugin nothing in the position, it takes the position by itself as default. Therefore i changed the position on the side less then -1 to the same value on the positive side. So i got on both side of the x-axis (which in your case is -1 unfortunately) the same values.

Comment: I've looked at your setup and I thank you for your time. I will try it out. I did however manage to get it to not offset but it's not symmetrical, not sure how, I just played around, but by adding the normal and vector math nodes worked like a charm tbh. 

Check screenshot of my fix

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o-sGK0ppPeY2GMjdPe-vev6gB-jSldaL/view?usp=share_link

I originally thought is was symmetrical but I checked again and noticed, thank you for your help.